# Is it possible to prove certain conjectures have no proof?

Tags: solution-verification, conjectures, incompleteness, goldbachs-conjecture

We will use Goldbach's conjecture as an example$^1$. It is either **true or false** that every even number greater than 2 is the sum of two primes. Let's take a look at these two scenarios.

**Goldbach's conjecture is true:** If it is true it might be provable or it might not be. We currently don't know.

**Goldbach's conjecture is false:** If it is false, it definitely has a disproof as a counterexample must exist. A counterexample would be an even number that is not the sum of two primes.

If someone claims to have proven that Goldbach's conjecture has no proof, we can infer that Goldbach's conjecture must be true. This is because **it can only have no proof if the conjecture is true**. As a result, by proving that the conjecture has no proof, the conjecture has been shown to be true and hence proven.

There appears to be a clear contradiction here and hence I believe that it is impossible to prove that Goldbach's conjecture has no proof. **Is there an issue with my reasoning or is it possible to prove that Goldbach's conjecture has no proof?**

*1 - Any conjecture that can be proven false with a counterexample would be applicable here.*

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27755/knuths-intuition-that-goldbach-might-be-unprovable/

Comment: The continuum hypothesis was proved to be independent after being conjectured so it's possible.

Comment: "It can only have no proof if the conjecture is true", there are also false statements about natural numbers which have no proof. The problem is, given a theory T,the notions of "truth" and "provability" for a statement only coincide when the T is complete and sound. The theory of arithmetic (most usually Peano's axioms) was shown to be incomplete by Gödel.

Comment: When you assert a statement has no proof, you have to state what logical systems you are talking about. It is true that if Goldbach's conjecture is false (in the intuitive sense), then it cannot be proved in PA or any other [$\omega$-consistent theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ω-consistent_theory). (But you have to believe PA is consistent to believe that.)

Comment: @AdamRubinson no that's false. The reason is that some true statements are unprovable so their negation would be false but also unprovable otherwise the truth of the statement could be inferred from it.

Comment: It is not necessary to find a counterexample. It is enough to prove that counterexample exists - and we currently do not know it is provable or not.

Comment: Assuming that the Goldbach conjecture is true and ZFC is consistent, it is well possible that ZFC cannot prove the Goldbach conjecture , although it is expected that ZFC is strong enough to solve "natural" problems (not particularly designed for the purpose to be true but unprovable). The continuum hypothesis is a statement that differs in a crucial way from the Goldbach conjecture. We can check every even number whether it is the sum of two primes, but we have no clearcut decision whether any given set disproves the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: The Goldbach conjecture also has no proof if it is false. So, "unprovable" does not imply "true". But if we can prove within ZFC that the Goldbach conjecture is independent of PA (this might be possible), then we have proven it , assuming the consistency of ZFC.